# vertica integration with apache kafka error

Tags: apache-kafka, vertica

Could you please help me with the following issue?
I have an installed vertica 9.3 on one host and installed apache kafka on second host. I want integration vertica with apache kafka (2.4.0). I configure by official vertica's guide, but, when I try to make source:

```
 vkconfig source --create --cluster kafka_weblog --source test --partitions 1 --conf /opt/vertica/packages/kafka/config/my.conf
```

I get error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.vertica.solutions.kafka.exception.ConfigurationException: ERROR: [[Vertica][VJDBC](5861) ERROR: Error calling processPartition() in User Function KafkaListTopics at [/data/qb_workspaces/jenkins2/ReleaseBuilds/Grader/REL-9_3_1-x_grader/build/udx/supported/kafka/KafkaUtil.cpp:163], error code: 0, message: Error getting metadata: [Local: Broker transport failure]]
        at com.vertica.solutions.kafka.model.StreamSource.validateConfiguration(StreamSource.java:248)
        at com.vertica.solutions.kafka.model.StreamSource.setFromMapAndValidate(StreamSource.java:194)
        at com.vertica.solutions.kafka.model.StreamModel.<init>(StreamModel.java:93)
        at com.vertica.solutions.kafka.model.StreamSource.<init>(StreamSource.java:44)
        at com.vertica.solutions.kafka.cli.SourceCLI.getNewModel(SourceCLI.java:62)
        at com.vertica.solutions.kafka.cli.SourceCLI.getNewModel(SourceCLI.java:13)
        at com.vertica.solutions.kafka.cli.CLI.run(CLI.java:59)
        at com.vertica.solutions.kafka.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:141)
        at com.vertica.solutions.kafka.cli.SourceCLI.main(SourceCLI.java:29)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: [Vertica][VJDBC](5861) ERROR: Error calling processPartition() in User Function KafkaListTopics at [/data/qb_workspaces/jenkins2/ReleaseBuilds/Grader/REL-9_3_1-x_grader/build/udx/supported/kafka/KafkaUtil.cpp:163], error code: 0, message: Error getting metadata: [Local: Broker transport failure]
        at com.vertica.util.ServerErrorData.buildException(Unknown Source)
        at com.vertica.dataengine.VResultSet.fetchChunk(Unknown Source)
        at com.vertica.dataengine.VResultSet.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at com.vertica.dataengine.VQueryExecutor.readExecuteResponse(Unknown Source)
        at com.vertica.dataengine.VQueryExecutor.handleExecuteResponse(Unknown Source)
        at com.vertica.dataengine.VQueryExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.vertica.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeWithParams(Unknown Source)
        at com.vertica.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.vertica.solutions.kafka.model.StreamSource.validateConfiguration(StreamSource.java:227)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: com.vertica.support.exceptions.NonTransientException: [Vertica][VJDBC](5861) ERROR: Error calling processPartition() in User Function KafkaListTopics at [/data/qb_workspaces/jenkins2/ReleaseBuilds/Grader/REL-9_3_1-x_grader/build/udx/supported/kafka/KafkaUtil.cpp:163], error code: 0, message: Error getting metadata: [Local: Broker transport failure]
```

If I show table `weblog_sched.stream_clusters`, then there is `localhost:9092` in the column hosts, but not my ip-address of my kafka server (`192.168.0.8`), although when I created the cluster I specified the address of the kafka server:

```
vkconfig cluster --create --cluster kafka_weblog --hosts 192.168.0.8:9092 --conf /opt/vertica/packages/kafka/config/my.conf
```

Why is that? (I think, that this error is associated with an incorrect entry in `weblog_sched.stream_clusters`)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add Kafka hosts in `/etc/hosts` file of Vertica Cluster. The issue should be resolved. If this is the case, then it means that your `advertised.listeners` have been configured incorrectly.

---

Hardcoding your hosts under `/etc/hosts` is definitely not the best approach. You must fix your `advertised.listeners` as a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of debugging this..

1. Try `telnet 192.168.0.8 9092`. If you are able to telnet, then the port is open and Kafka is running and is accessible from the place where you are executing the telnet command. If you are not able to connect via telnet, then you can try this..

   1. Check your firewall or iptables rules and allow 9092 port on that machine.
      Ex: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9092 -j ACCEPT`
   2. If you are still not able to access it, try disabling or allowing that port in your firewall in your system (like ufw, firewalld) etc'
2. Check your `advertised.listeners` broker configuration. Ensure that you have set it to `PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.8:9092` (if you are using the PLAINTEXT). This most likely may solve your problem.